# Amadeus Slef-Service API content sourcing

Tags: amadeus

after investigating Hotel Search API under Amadeus Self-Service API I still have some uncertainties regarding Self-Service API and content sourcing.

From my understanding using Self-Service API we **CAN NOT** choose content sourcing for data, so that leads me to the conclusion that it is using by default **Amadeus GDS** as a content source and that only in Enterprise API there is a way of choosing a content source.  Does anyone know if my reasoning is correct?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

using the API you have 2 alternatives to retrieve Hotel Information:

-If you want to return detailed information on a hotel or book the hotel you need to use the 'subType' parameter set to 'HOTEL_GDS'.

-If you want to list all the hotels available in an area but without more information or the booking option (to build a map for example). You can use 'HOTEL_LEISURE' to get more content.

Using the first option, you could retrieve Hotel information about 150k hotels, but using the second one, you could retrieve hotel information about 1 Million of Hotels, but some of them, will be impossible to continue the booking operative.

So, depending of your process, you could get more or less Hotel Information.

Juan Antonio